# Angular momentum in curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, angular-momentum, symmetry, group-representations

It is known that the angular momentum components are also a representation of the $SU(2)$ generators. Given a non-trivial spacetime, say a black hole of some kind or AdS space, how can one define the action of $SU(2)$? Does one compute generalized angular momentum components for that space or is there another procedure?

Answer (score 5):

First, let's go back to flat space.

The mentioned SU(2) algebra is just a part of the 10-dimensional Poincare algebra - the algebra of isometries of Minkowski space-time. The generators of isometries are called Killing vector fields, you can easily show that these (they come with the Lie bracket, as usual) obey the Poincare algebra.

Because isometries (by definition) do not change the metric, the *flat-space* action is left invariant. This gives you ten Noether currents, specifically the four currents forming the stress-energy tensor $T_{\nu}^{\mu}$ and six forming the angular-momentum tensor $M_{\alpha \beta}^{\mu}$.

Now to the general case.

Because each diffeomorphism is now a symmetry of the action, there are infinitely many conserved currents, but none of them can actually be called 'angular momentum'. There still is a notion of stress-energy tensor, because infinitesimal deffeomorphisms are kind of like 'local (gauge) translations'. But this tensor is only covariantly conserved (the so-called problem of energy in GR).

In order to find the conserved currents analogous to the usual angular momentum, you have to recover the algebra of Killing vector fields of your space.

Comment: "*you have to recover the algebra of Killing vector fields of your space*" - whereby you mean the Killing vector fields of the particular space or Einstein Field Equation solution under consideration, right?

Comment: Right - of a particular space in which you are interested in.

Comment: Diffeomorphisms are **not** symmetries since to have an **invariant** action you should apply them to the metric too, which is not a dynamical field but a background, i.e., assigned, field. The symmetries act on the dynamical fields only,  unless you include the gravitational field in this set of variables (but it does not seem the case here). The only *geometric* transformations giving rise to conserved currents are Killing symmetries, which are very few.   If the dynamical fields have some internal space, there are other possible non-geometrical symmetries producing conserved currents.

Comment: But the SU(2) generators are represented by the quantum mehanical version of the angular momentum components. How am I to read off these, simply by having constructed the angular momentum tensor in the given spacetime?

Comment: Valter Moretti - I meant that diffeomorphisms are symmetries of the complete theory (fields + metric). It is the reason why their Noether currents aren't interesting.

Comment: Cala, given the angular momentum tensor, it's components $M_{12}^{\mu}$, $M_{23}^{\mu}$ and $M_{13}^{\mu}$ *in flat space* form the SU(2) algebra. But in the general background, there could be no such thing as angular momentum.

Comment: Valter Moretti - But to find the symmetries which act only on fields we have to recover the Killing vector fields. I am sorry if it was unclear. I am also sorry for two separate comments - something is clearly wrong with my browser.

Comment: @Hindsight So finding the Killing vectors for that space, leads to the generators of the isometries. Could you point out a book or paper where explicit examples are given in some spacetime? The definition of the Killing equation seems a bit difficult to handle to me